# Creating an Ascii encryption function in python, advice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

I'm trying to create an encryption function in Python using the following functions.

```
def code_char(c, key):
    adj = ord('a') if c.islower() else ord('A') 
    return chr(adj + (ord(c)-adj+int(key))%26)
```

^Codes a character

```
def isletter(c):
    if 65 <= ord(c) <= 90:
        return True
    elif 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

^Checks if a character is a letter

The encryption function must include the `code_block` and `isletter(c)` functions

I'm looking to be able to input any length string and it encrypts it according to an 8-digit key.

I'd also like it to ignore any blank spaces, punctuation and anything that isn't a letter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with `code_char` as when you add `int(key)` you need to mod `%26` to ensure the letter stays as an ascii char:

```
def code_char(c, key):
    adj = ord('a') if c.islower() else ord('A')
    return chr(adj + (ord(c)-adj+int(key))%26)
```

Result:

```
>>> encrypt("This is  a   secret  message!!", "12345678")
'Ujlw ny  h   afeuiy  slatcji!!'
```

You can of course improve your code, for example your `code_block` could be rewritten:

```
import itertools as it

def code_block(word, key):
    k = it.cycle(key)
    return "".join(code_char(c, next(k)) if isletter(c) else c for c in word)
```

You can also rewrite your `isletter()`:

```
def isletter(c):
    return c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

You can leverage the `string` module that already defines this:

```
import string
def isletter(c):
    return c in string.ascii_letters
```

And finally your `encrypt()` you are unnecessarily creating a list and `''.join()` and is simply just:

```
def encrypt(s, key):   # string is a module - may clash
    return code_block(s, key)
```

Note: `if 65 <= ord(c) <= 90:` is perfectly legal and does what you expect it to do in Python.

Comment: I need to write the opposie to `code_char` now `decode_char` do I reverse the signs of the `code_char` function? I'm trying but nothing I try is giving me `This is a secret message!!`???

Comment: Just `-int(key)`

Answer (score 0):

done some changes ...with the `isletter`

```
def isletter(c):
    if 65 <= ord(c) and ord(c) <= 90:
        return True
    elif 97 <= ord(c) and ord(c) <= 122:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

in your old code :

```
65<=ord(c)<=90
```

`65<=ord(c)` will give some boolean value which is then compared with the `90`. *[AC: Not true in python]*

`code_char` function changes:

```
def code_char(c, key):
    tmp=ord(c)+int(key)
    if(tmp>122):
        return chr(tmp-26)
    else:
        return chr(tmp)
```

Comment: This gives a invalid syntax message?

Comment: It's not in the shell, as I press F5 to run the program, a window pops up saying invalid syntax and the second & is highlighted red

Comment: What are the changes?

Comment: when you add character and number they  is a chance they become non letter .

Comment: How do I prevent this and make it go back to the beginning of the alphabet?

Comment: I now have some blank squares followed by the exclamation points as an output?

Comment: now it will work ... use code_char and isletter again your code .

Comment: but after solving that i realy dont know what i have done ... :P

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan `0 <= x <= 60` is perfectly legal and works as expected in python.

Comment: `code_char('Z', '5')` would still give the incorrect result.

Comment: i get realy rusty on python .. if you lie to edit and suggest please do .. thanks in advance ..